# How to know if the a column contains all NULLs

Tags: sql, postgresql, null

how to know if all the columns contain only null values, for example

```
ID         | col1     | col2      |col3       | col4     
-----------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------
 1         | Null     |Null       | with value| with value
 2         |with value|Null       | with value| with value
 3         |with value|Null       | Null      | Null    
 4         |with value|Null       | with value| with value
 5         |with value|Null       | Null      | Null  
 6         |Null      |Null       | Null      | Null    
 7         |with value|Null       | with value| with value
 8         |with value|Null       | Null      | Null
```

only `col2` is NULL, so the result should be `col2` only.

```
ID         | col2     |
-----------+----------+
 1         |Null      |
 2         |Null      |
 3         |Null      |
 4         |Null      |
 5         |Null      |
 6         |Null      |
 7         |Null      |
 8         |Null      |
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A query result-set has a defined set of columns, independent of table contents.

Comment: That's not possible, because the columns that a result have has to be known before the query executes. What you could achieve is a single row with the column's name as a string value

Comment: If `count(col) = 0`, the column contains nothing but null values.

Comment: If `min(col) is null` or `max(col) is null` works too.

Answer (score 5):

You count the columns that are not NULL:

```
SELECT 0 = count(col1) AS col1_all_null,
       0 = count(col2) AS col2_all_null,
       ...
FROM mytable;
```

This makes use of the fact that aggregate functions ignore NULL values (well, almost all at least).

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want all rows for the columns that are all `NULL`?  You know what the values are.

Further, a SQL query can only return a fixed set of columns, so you can't filter the columns.  If you just want a list of the column names all of whose values are `NULL`, you can concatenate the names together:

```
select concat_ws(',',
                 (case when count(col1) = 0 then 'col1' end),
                 (case when count(col2) = 0 then 'col2' end),
                 (case when count(col3) = 0 then 'col3' end)
                )
from t;
```